# 相関副参照でSELECTしたレコードをDELETEするSQLについて。

Tags: sql, database, db2

相関副参照でSELECTしたレコードをDELETEするSQLについて。SELECTしてる間はロックしないようにする（純粋にDELETEのときだけロックする）方法はありませんか？

Answer (score 0):

相関サブクエリを使用して、`SELECT` ステートメントを使用してターゲット レコードを取得します。
一意の識別子を使用して、取得したレコードに対して `SELECT` ステートメントを再度実行します。
たとえば、このコードは次のようになります。

```
DELETE FROM テーブル名
WHERE 識別子 IN (
    SELECT 識別子
    FROM テーブル名
    WHERE 条件
    FOR UPDATE
);

DELETE FROM users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM users
    WHERE age < 20
    FOR UPDATE
);
```